# How do I target specific button for click event

Tags: reactjs

When I click on the + every list is displayed and if I click on the - everything is hidden. How can I click on specific button and it displays the content or hide as the case may be. Right now a click on any of the button either hides or shows.

```
 { showing ? <button onClick={(e) => setShowing(false)}>-</button> : <button onClick={(e) => setShowing({showing:  showing})}>+</button>
                          }
                              { showing 
                              ? student.grades.map((grade, index) => (
                              <span className="grade" key={index}>Test {index}: {grade}</span>
                          )) : <span></span>
                        
                        }
```

Comment: You should fix your formatting.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [categories and sub categories in ReactJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64228315/categories-and-sub-categories-in-reactjs)

Comment: @idbentley I tried it but didn't solve it. I want to target specific event

Answer (score 0):

Your plus function seems to be invalid, try something like this:

For the minus (-):

```
<button onClick={(e) => setShowing(false)}>-</button>
```

For the plus (+):

```
<button onClick={(e) => setShowing(true)}>+</button>
```

Comment: I have corrected still the same result. I need eventlistener to know which id of the button clicked but I don't know how

Answer (score 0):

You either need to keep track of a `showing` state variable for each row, or a more "React" style solution would be to create another component for each row, and let them each have one state variable:

```
function myComponent(props) {
    const { students } = props.students; // or wherever these come from - you didn't specify

    return students.map((student) => <StudentRow {...student} />});
}
function StudentRow (props) {
    const [showing, setShowing] = useState(false); // or true if they default visible

    return (<>
        { showing ? <button onClick={(e) => setShowing(false)}>-</button> : <button onClick={(e) => setShowing(true)}>+</button>}
        { showing ? student.grades.map((grade, index) => (
                          <span className="grade" key={index}>Test {index}: {grade}</span>
                      )) : <span></span>}
         </>);
}
```

You could refactor this `StudentRow` component to be more easily readable as:

```
function StudentRow (props) {
    const [showing, setShowing] = useState(false); // or true if they default visible
    if (!showing) {
        return <button onClick={(e) => setShowing(true)}>+</button>;
    } else {
        return (<>
            <button onClick={(e) => setShowing(false)}>-</button>
            {student.grades.map((grade, index) => (
                          <span className="grade" key={index}>Test {index}: {grade}</span>
                 ))}
         </>);
}
```